# Cycles and EEVEE strange polygon problems

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh, faces, eevee-render-engine

to the point: Why are polygons visible when rendering on cycles (Attention to the wheel), but not on eevee? hdri is same on both renders. The wheel has a smooth shade. In solid mode, everything is fine, and the mesh is almost perfect. Both renderings were through f12. thanks.

[image]

Comment: Check your material settings, are you using alpha blend? Change to opaque and see if that helps.

Comment: Are you certain that this isn't just a reflection of wood panels? Perhaps you can put the wheel in a different environment to check if this effect still occurs.

Comment: The problem has solven. I just changed the normal texture of wheel to non-color and it works. I dont know why this helped, anyway it's over.